# How would I go about filtering this JavaScript object efficiently?

Tags: javascript, object, nested, filtering

I have the following data:

```
let types = ["A", "C"];

let data = {
  301: {
    name: "Suite",
    fields: [
      [null, null, null, null, null, null],
      [
        null,
        null,
        {
          type: "A",
        },
        {
          type: "A",
        },
        null,
        null,
      ],
      [null, null, null, null, null, null],
      [null, null, null, null, null, null],
      [null, null, null, null, null, null],
      [null, null, null, null, null, null],
      [null, null, null, null, null, null],
    ],
  },
  302: {
    name: "Suite",
    fields: [
      [null, null, null, null, null, null],
      [
        {
          type: "B",
        },
        {
          type: "B",
        },
        {
          type: "B",
        },
        {
          type: "B",
        },
        null,
        null,
      ],
      [null, null, null, null, null, null],
      [null, null, null, null, null, null],
      [null, null, null, null, null, null],
      [null, null, null, null, null, null],
      [null, null, null, null, null, null],
    ],
  },
};
```

in the fields array there is either null or an object, if there is an object I want to check wether that object has a type that is included in types, if it isn't I want to set that array value to null aswell, otherwise just skip it.

How would I do this? Any help appreciated.

I tried this approach, which works but is really terrible:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
  data[key].fields.forEach((fieldArray, fieldArrayIndex) => {
    fieldArray.forEach((field, fieldIndex) => {
      if (field) {
        if (!types.includes(field.type)) {
          fieldArray[fieldIndex] = null;
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: That approach looks pretty much fine to me, to be honest.

Comment: Really? I was a bit worried about the number of loops, thought something like reduce might work better.

Comment: `reduce` would do the same number of iterations.

Comment: A tiny improvement would be to use `Object.values()` instead of `Object.keys()` (if it's available in the JS/ES version you're targeting), but that's rather minor.